# Как Вывести значение, которое дало "true" в "исключающем или"

Tags: java

В этом коде предлагается ввести три значения, если два числа из трех равны, то их нужно вывести на экран.  Как понять какое из трех равенств возвратило "true"?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = scanner.nextInt();
int b = scanner.nextInt();
int c = scanner.nextInt();

if ( a==b ^ a==c ^ b==c  ) \\ как понять какое из трех равенств возвратило "true"
    System.out.println(  );
```

Comment: Сделать три if(..)?

Comment: Никак. Будет true даже если все три равны.

Comment: Кстати, ваше неравенство неверно. true ^ true ^ true выдаст true, хотя должно false.

Comment: это тройное исключающее или.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно несколько условий

```
 if ( a==b && a!=c) {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
    if ( a==c && a!=b) {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    if ( c==b && a!=c) {
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Возвращает номер выражения:

```
public static int XOR(boolean... booleans){
    int trueNumber = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < booleans.length; i++){
        if(booleans[i]){
            if(trueNumber == -1){
                trueNumber = i + 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    return trueNumber;
}
```

Если xor == false, то возвращает -1